# Using foreach to display results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to write some sort of forum homepage, based off work someone else did. Here's what I've got so far:

## Forums

```
<?php
 $crumbs = explode(",", $user['data']['depts']);

 foreach ($crumbs as &$value) {
     $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_depts WHERE id = '" . $value . "'");
     $crumb = $data->fetch_assoc();
     $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_forums WHERE deptid = '" . $value . "'");
     $forumcount = $data->num_rows;
     $forum = $data->fetch_assoc();
?>


<div class="h3top"><?php echo $crumb['name']; ?></div>
<div class="info2alt">
<?php
     while (($row = $data->fetch_array()) !== FALSE) {
         $forum[] = $row;
     }

     foreach ($forum as $row) {

         if ($forumcount >= 1) {
             if ($forum['lastpost'] == "") {
                 $forum['lastpost'] = "--";
             }
?>
            <div class="info4">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" class="zebraodd"><a href="/forums/viewforum?id=<?php echo $forum['fid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
                        <td width="10%">Threads: <?php echo $forum['threadcount']; ?><br />Posts: <?php echo $forum['postcount']; ?></td>
                        <td width="35%">Last Post: <?php echo $forum['lastpost']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
<?php
 }
?>
        <?php if ($forumcount >= 1) { ?>
            <div class="info3bottom"></div>

            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php
 }
?>
```

This is the current data in the table:

[image: Table Data]

Now, when I try to use this code, I get this:[image: Issue], such that the first one is shown so many times, however, the next one does not appear.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>you want to use `$value['threadcount']` etc. `$forum` is the array containing all the rows. i wonder that you get some output at all …</strike>

`fetch_assoc()` will only fetch a single row from the resultset. you'd have to use a loop to fill an array:

```
while(($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) !== FALSE) {
  $forum[] = $row;
}
```

you can then iterate over your `$forum` array with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($forum as $row) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($row['threadcount']);
  // etc.
}
```

---

trying to fix this mess …

```
<?php

$crumbs = explode(",", $user['data']['depts']);

foreach ($crumbs as $crumb) { ?>
  <div class="h3top"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($crumb['name']);?></div>
<?
}

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_forums WHERE deptid = " . (int)$id . "");
$forumcount = $result->num_rows;

while(($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) !== FALSE) {
  if ($row['lastpost'] == "") { $row['lastpost'] = "--";}
?>
  <div class="info2alt">
  <div class="info4">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
  <td width="55%" align="left" valign="middle" class="zebraodd"><a href="/forums/viewforum?id=<?php echo urlencode($forum['fid']); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($forum['name']); ?></a></td>
  <td width="10%">Threads: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($forum['threadcount']); ?><br />Posts: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($forum['postcount']); ?></td>
  <td width="35%">Last Post: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($forum['lastpost']); ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>

  <div class="info3bottom"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Using $value gives me a serialised string, then finishes with: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/erp/public_html/forums/home.php on line 28. The id, at this point is still 1.

Comment: still doesn't like it: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Comment: additionally, i think the if has to be outside your foreach loop. there is more than a single thing fishy in this code (e.g. sqli and xss)

Comment: Hi, which if are you talking about?

Comment: your indentation is a mess. i think you run a query to get all forum entries for each breadcrumb. plus, you are always using the wrong variable inside the foreach loop (i.e. the array instead of the current item).

Comment: Let me try to redo the indentation.

Comment: Basically, as you said - I'm running a query to get the list of categories. Then, using that, I'm running a second query to get each forum, and its information. This is where I'm having the issue.

Comment: It would help if I had : $forum = array();. It's working now! Cheers.